# Dynamically create metadata and associate it with File using Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, managed-metadata, metadata

Is there any way to dynamically add metadata in the upload file. I am using the following code in this regard.

```
File uploadFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(location);
//check out to make sure not to create multiple versions
if (!list.ForceCheckout)
    uploadFile.CheckOut();

//setting metadata here
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Status"] = "In-Progress";
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//overwrite to make sure not to create multiple versions
uploadFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Upon running above code, i am getting this error:

***Column 'Status' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.***

Now is there any way to dynamically create it programmatically because i preferably don't want to create it using designer?

Answer (score 0):

For adding status column :

```
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
            Field fild = web.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Status");
            list.Fields.Add(fild);
            list.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Try with internal name of status column:

uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["_Status"] = "In-Progress";

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: At what line you are getting error. There are 2 status columns in sharepoint. One with static name "_Status" and one with "DecisionStatus". You can try with 2nd one.

Comment: So you have not added the status column in sharepoint library?

Comment: First add the status column then update. I have added the code to add create site column